# rbinom is producing higher than expected amounts of success

Tags: r, for-loop

I was just attempting to recreate an example using the `rbinom` function, but the numbers of "successes" is a lot higher than I would be expecting due to the low probabilities.

```
numSamples <- 10000 #number of samples to be drawn from population
numTrials <- 100 #this is the sample size (size of each sample)
probs <- seq(0.001, 0.9999, 0.01) 

for (i in 1:length(probs)) {
  x <- rbinom(n = numSamples, size = numTrials, prob = probs[i])
}
```

Everything seems straightforward, except that I am getting the number of success to be between 97 - 100 for all of the samples. When I do a few test cases manually using the smaller probabilities such as 0.001 I get the number of successes expected: 0. So there is an issue in how my `for` loop is reading things. What is going wrong ?

Comment: is there a reason you are discarding (overwriting) `x` each pass except the last?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I did `mx <- numeric(length(probs)); for (i in 1:length(probs)) { mx[i] <- mean(rbinom(n = numSamples, size = numTrials, prob = probs[i])) }` and the values are just about as expected.  Maybe, as @r2evans suggests, you are failing to save the interim values ... ?

Comment: @r2evans I thin that is the issue. I was afraid that was what was happening.  I see where the mistake is, I should have `x[i] = rbinom(n = numSamples, size = numTrials, prob = probs[i])`..........at least I think that is where the mistake is. Edit: just tried that but now the legths of my vectors are messed up

Comment: Can we have a little bit more context (e.g.: what data structure do you want to end up with)?

Comment: Sorry Ben. I was anticipating a simple vector outputting the number of successes for each of the 10000 samples with respect to the probability from the `probs` vector. I think in order for me to have that I'm going to have to increase the length of the `probs` vector be equal to the length of the`numSamples` vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to get all the samples:

```r
res <- list()
for (i in 1:length(probs)) {
  res <- c(res,
    list(rbinom(n = numSamples, size = numTrials, prob = probs[i]))
}
```

You can then `unlist(res)` to get one long vector, or `do.call(rbind, res)` to collapse to a matrix. Growing a list this way and then collapsing it doesn't incur the same performance penalty as growing a vector.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks for the assistance. Enjoy your weekend.

Comment: Quick question: why did you have to add `res` to the concatenation in the first component? i.e `c(res, list(stuff)`?

Comment: because I want to add the `rbinom()` result to the existing `res()` list (which starts empty)